# TinyMCE, IE9, stripping <script> tags

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

Good evening, first question here!

I've looked and I've looked, and I've found solutions that don't work. My problem is that IE9 (and 8, 7 etc) will strip  tags in TinyMCE 3.4.3.2.

I'm afraid my circumstances are a little unique: I'm working with an existing CMS (custom) which is a little outdated, made in Java, and isn't XHTML-friendly. There is a custom plugin that allows you to insert some script code, then surrounds it with `CDATA` tags. Essentially:

`insertHTML(document.videoForm.myobj.value);`

Where insertHTML, well, inserts it where the cursor was. Now, this works fantastically in Chrome, Firefox etc, but fails in IE. After inserting the script via a popup textarea box, then using TinyMCE's built in HTML viewer, the `<script>` tags disappear. Putting a `<br />` before the script tags makes it work for some reason, but this is undesirable as many clients don't know what HTML is.

Using IE9's developer...thing...I found some errors.
`HTML1114: Codepage unicode from (UNICODE byte order mark) overrides conflicting codepage windows-1252 from (11)`
Triggered by the doctype
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Transitional.dtd">`
**WHICH IS WRONG, I KNOW**, and I want to change it, but I am under quite strict limitations here, and I don't have access to wherever that doctype is rendered.

Another thing: here is the extended_valid_elements thingymajig:

```
extended_valid_elements: "SCRIPT[language<JavaScript?JavaScript1.1?JavaScript1.2?JScript?php?VBScript|src|wgtsrc|type<text/javascript?mce-text/javascript?javascript],script[language<JavaScript?JavaScript1.1?JavaScript1.2?JScript?php?VBScript|src|wgtsrc|type<text/javascript?mce-text/javascript?javascript],form[name|method|action|id|target|onsubmit],FORM[name|method|action|id|onclick|target|onsubmit],embed[src|type|wmode|width|height],object[class|id|classid|codebase|width|height]"
```

If you can spot anything in there that could throw IE off, do point it out. If you can tell me that the strange doctype is throwing it off, let me know and I'll ask my employer where he buried that...

**TL;DR:** IE9 strips  tags in TinyMCE 3.4.3.2, possibly due to doctype.

Comment: Most browsers don't actually care about doctypes that much and only use them to determine between "standards" and quirks rendering modes (by basically looking if there is a doctype *at all* or not). It is probably something else then.

Answer (score 0):

Are the script tags self closing? If they are self closing script tags then IE will have issues.

[Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Example of self closing script tag:

```
<script src="" />
```

IE compatible format:

```
<script src=""></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the tags weren't self-closing. At present I'm just inserting a <br /> which my boss is happy with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to this SO question:
[Why HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457111/why-html1113-document-mode-restart-from-ie9-standards-to-quirks)

See the solution there.