# IE HTML1114 Error with custom CLeditor button

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, fine-uploader, cleditor

I am using CLeditor, Fineuploader, and Bootstrap to create a custom button that pops up a more advanced file upload Modal. But everytime I launch the modal I get an error and I have no idea how to fix it. Basically the whole browser freezes.

```
HTML1114: Codepage unicode from (UNICODE byte order mark) overrides conflicting codepage windows-1252 from (11)
```

I found what was going wrong this warning still displays but it carries on normally.

So CLeditor has a terrible design where it runs the command on custom buttons on click rather than waiting for the `buttonClick` callback to be run this created a situation where IE was calling `getRange(editor).pasteHTML(value)` with a value of `undefined` to mitigate it I just added my button name to the big if else if in the `buttonClick` event handler

```
// Image uploader
else if (buttonName === "uploadImage") {
  return;
}

// All other buttons AVOID THIS NONSENSE FOR CUSTOM BUTTONS!!!
else if (!execCommand(editor, data.command, data.value, data.useCSS, buttonDiv)) {
   return false;
}
```

Comment: How does the header in HTML looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the outputted header for "cleditor wysiwyg" (if I understand the code correct) is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

IE=Edge should be the very først line in `<head>`. Sounds very much like IE is switching back to quirksmode. See more detailed explanation explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10494507/1407478).

Comment: I Will have to check this tomorrow and let you know but that sounds like a good start. I tried something similar but had a charset as the first line not the http-equiv

Comment: Still getting the same warning when the modal is launched and then the browser crashes. Also getting a HTML1115 Warning when the wysiwyg is initialized

Comment: Problem turned out to be something different but this answer is the correct way to mitigate the HTML1114 error most of the time.