# Running a C# and a Javascript function on an asp button control?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I can get both the Javascript and the C# function to work just fine.

However, my Javascript function runs before the C#.

How do I get it to run after the C# function??

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
<asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
<div id="div2" style="height:70px; width:auto; text-align:center;">
<p><b>This is A View!!!</b></p>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
</div>

<div id="div1">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        OnClientClick="javascript:Highlit()" />
</div>
</asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Highlit() 
{
 $("#div2").effect("highlight", {}, 10000);
}
</script>

 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code behind:**

```
namespace jQuery_Highlight.jQuery_Highlight
{
public partial class jQuery_HighlightUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Changed";
    }
   }
}
```

Here is the code reflecting changes from the answers:

**Code behind**

```
namespace jQuery_Highlight.jQuery_Highlight
{
public partial class jQuery_HighlightUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Changed";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "TEST", "Highlit();", true);
    }
   }
   }




 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
 <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
 <div id="div2" style="height:70px; width:auto; text-align:center;">
 <p><b>This is A View!!!</b></p>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 </div>

 <div id="div1">
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
 </div>
 </asp:View>
 </asp:MultiView>

 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type="text/javascript">

function Highlit() {
    $("#div2").effect("highlight", { color: "#9499FC" }, 10000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to get the javascript to run after is to add a script reference in your Button1_Click event.

Example Code for standard postback:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Changed";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "PostButton1_ClickScript", "Highlit();", true);
}
```

As noted by others, be sure to remove your OnClientClick event.  Also, consider moving your "Highlit" script outside of the update panel.

Additionally, since you are in an update panel, you will need to use the following example code for a Partial Postback:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Changed";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "PostButton1_ClickScript", "Highlit();", true);
}
```

Comment: I was just going to say the same thing!

Comment: @J Torres Thanks! But I catn seem to get the javascript to run. I got rid of the OnClientClick event and moved my jScript function outside the updatepanel. Am I missing anything?

Comment: When you click the button, I'm assuming the label updates.  If you use Firebug or some other similar utility, does the updated javascript show up on the page?  Any script errors?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it look slike I might already have a div with the same id unless I understood this error wrong:    HTML1114: Codepage unicode from (UNICODE byte order mark) overrides conflicting codepage windows-1252 from (11) 
Home.aspx

Comment: Well treid it with a different div id and still the same warning

Comment: [This is the only reasonable reference I've seen to that error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811848/tinymce-ie9-stripping-script-tags).  When are you receiving that error?

Comment: As soon as I click the button.

Comment: That seems to be a red-herring error and is normally a result (best I can surmise) as a combination of copy and paste and IE9 browser.  Are you using IE9?

Comment: Best thing I can suggest is copy everything in your ASPX into notepad, then copy it back.  If I remember correctly, that SHOULD remove the weird formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register a ClientScript at the end of Button1_Click event
and remove OnClientClick="javascript:Highlit()"

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ANYNAME", "javascript:Highlit();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `OnClientClick` attribute, and add the call as a startup script, so that it runs after the page has loaded:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Label1.Text = "Changed";
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "start", "Highlit();", true);
}
```

Side note: When you use the `OnClientClick` attribute, the code should not start with `javascript:`. That's only used when you put script in a `href` attribute in a link.

Comment: That actually won't work in this his exact instance because he is within an Update Panel.  You must use ScriptManager to inject additional scripts during partial postbacks.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.